# How to correctly infer or declare the type of a cast to array function with typescript with mixed arguments?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to have a really simple tool to cast a value to an array if needed. Like this :

```js
function castToArray(args: unknown) {
  return Array.isArray(args) ? args : [args];
}
```

So far so good.

Ideally, I'm expecting typescript to infer the type of the array from the `args` type. But without no more burden, TS is logically typing output as `any[]`.

To solve this, I've tried to used a naive approach with generics :

```js
function castToArray<T>(args: T) {
   return Array.isArray(args) ? args : [args];
}
```

Now, I have a `(T & any[]) | T[]` return type **but** a single item is sadly still be treated as `any` type.

I then tried to define a conditional return type like so :

```js
function castToArray<T>(args: T): T extends any[] ? T : T[] {
    return Array.isArray(args) ? args : [args];
}
```

It works great to type output except that TS is now complaining about invalid assignation :

```
Type '(T & any[]) | T[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends any[] ? T : T[]'.
  Type 'T & any[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends any[] ? T : T[]'
```

What I am missing here ?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgZygFTgQQE54oCeAQugKYAUKeA5mgFyLgDWYcA7mAJSIDeAKETC85KCDxJ8hIgDoYaacWp00vAPyIa9REwDa2tAF0A3AIC+AgQBsxWggAZEAXmTosuAsTJoqARm4zWyhEADcUaydXGjwHPQdTK1BIWAQ3DGwlIgBZGAATAB5MAD4VeiZMXkFhRFFxSUQs+UUvIjK1RE1DXUQDVUTLGzsYvxd0jyzcvMoAoLtw61Hogj94xKGQmIAmMdQMzxkpyj0-I0CNsIid5bxVhLMBZOh4JD2J1oA5cgAPKCLSwwVbgVRA-KDkMB5NBaMBEPRGTqITA9TDw-hCGp1CRSVrNLLtDT2HT6QwDKzBex4ADMu3cmU+YJm5wpCxpNypaweFJiABZafssl9fsdTsz5hE+TceZygA)

Thanks !

Comment: You're missing that TS is unable to understand generic conditional types well enough to verify via control flow analysis; see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for the relevant open feature request about it.  In your case I'd recommend refactoring to avoid conditional types, perhaps [like this playground link shows](https://tsplay.dev/WJxEDN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Using T | T[] seems absolutely counterintuitive to me but it's doing as well as that my last try with no error :) You can provide your answer, I'll accept it at once. Thanks a lot (again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
function castToArray<T>(args: T): T extends any[] ? T : T[] {
    return Array.isArray(args) ? args : [args];
}
```

is that TypeScript is currently (up to and including TS5.1) unable to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to affect [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *type parameters* like `T`.  When you check `Array.isArray(args)`, that acts as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) on `args` (so `args` can be narrowed from `T` to something like `T & any[]`), but it has no effect whatsoever on `T`.  The compiler really has no idea what sorts of values might actually be assignable to a generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `T extends any[] ? T : T[]`.  So it gives up and complains.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asking for some fix to this that would allow you to implement a generic function returning a conditional type without [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  For now, though it's not part of the language.

And it's not immediately obvious how to implement such a feature; it's hard to describe what effect `Array.isArray(args)` should have on `T`.  You might expect that `T` could be re-[constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `T extends any[]`, but that's not valid; it's more like `any[] extends T`, since `T` could be some *supertype* of `any[]`.  But it wouldn't be valid to constrain `T` from below like `any[] extends T` *either*, because `T` could indeed also be a *subtype* of `any[]`.  The check does something to `T` like "there is some overlap between `any[]` and `T`". See [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for a similar discussion.

For now, if you want that to compile, you'll need to just tell the compiler not to worry about it with a type assertion:

```
function castToArray<T>(args: T) {
    return (Array.isArray(args) ? args : [args]) as (
        T extends any[] ? T : T[]);
}
```

---

Instead the current way to implement something like this without assertions is to "reverse" the constraint and think of `T` as the element type of the array no matter what, and accept an `args` which might or might not be `T` or an array of `T`:

```
function castToArray<T>(args: T | T[]): T[] {
    return Array.isArray(args) ? args : [args];
}
```

Now we are using the fact that the type guard acts on `args` and not `T`. If `Array.isArray(args)` returns `true` then the compiler concludes that `args` is of type `T[]` (this isn't technically type safe, since `T` itself might be an array type, but the compiler allows it and I'm not going to complain. Just be careful if you find yourself passing in arrays-of-arrays. I think it usually behaves properly, but it's something to watch).  And if it returns `false` then the compiler concludes that `args` is of type `T` (this *is* type safe, since it can't be `T[]` if it's not an array).  And thus the returned value is observably of type `T[]` to the compiler, and it compiles without error.

---

Either one of those should work, and it depends on your use cases which of those, if any, are better for your purposes.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuBhA9sACYCW2JhIANkgN4CwAUE0q0gGYCuw85hS8EFGwAVfCkyYQATwA8IgHwAKEJgDmUAFxIRASjos2RzBGydMwJEolTpAOhJQbMleqj6A-ElUak2gNo+UAC6+kJWhkZROkgQAB7YEMRQ3sDS-sFIXiJ+Ohm6ANyRSAC+TMVUpt6SAMxIALwCQqLiki4AjIUVVQBu1HWNqpg1-gAMwUXMjEaV2NWYACwNTcJiztJK-u2hkzO91EuDkgtjE+WMZVOgkLAIyABKEOwI2PiYYgCqwBSWDFNGXB4fEsglWrVs8mUQW0OQAPnlQjCMgZptEkCYzBZUG17I51q4NJ5qr4AkEzqjWJdunMhgMVi18Z1dmxZkg+lQ6bTTpNqfNDvS1jjNtsuhSkKz2fyhidxjypiUgA)

Comment: Great explanations. Thanks. Wish I can upvote more than once ^^